# Name for manipulative and or ambivalent language. example: "I know him" vs "I don't know him" both true and false depending on context and specifics

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Say you're acquainted with someone, you see each other around and give a nod or a hello. This is an acquaintance not a friend. You don't know much about the person.

To say "I know you" can be both true and false. Just as saying "I don't know you" can be both true or false. Depending on context and circumstances and how much 'know' the person means, the truth of the statement can change. It's an ambivalent language that can have multiple meanings.

Here is a different example(This may be something else entirely):

Say that your partner is being unfaithful to you but they go to a hotel. You're sure that this is happening and accuse them of having extra marital affairs at home. The person says "Baby oh baby, I haven't had anyone over, I swear it" in order to evade accountability, a break up or whatever else the reason. It's a true statement, but it's also false. It isn't overtly a lie, it's a lie by omission.

Is there a name for this kind of language? Always in flux, never delivers solid information, and can have different meanings from different angles.

Comment: This needs some re-formatting and serious editing...

Comment: This might get better traction at [interpersonal.se].

Comment: Thanks for the snarky comments fellas.  @Cascabel the formatting has nothing to do with my question. i'm disabled and it takes me a long time to type out words i"m not going to go correctly punctuate or format everything just toappease all the english snobs out there. And besides, wgat ekse would you have to do with your life if folks did everything "correctly."   I found out what I was looking for and it was actually a concept called Dialetheism

Comment: @Finu...Sorry. Please do not be offended. We are  trying to help. But that does not give you a pass on post issues. We are not actually here to 'answer every question'. We are preparing a type of encyclopedia here...we don't answer questions about relationships...

Comment: I have voted to re-open, but it still needs 2 more voters...